# How to convert MDX query to Calculated Named set in SSAS MOLAP cube

Tags: ssas, mdx, mdx-query

Could you please someone help here to convert below MDX query to cube calculated named set?
Thank you for your help in advance.

```
with dynamic set [NamedSetName] as
Exists(
filter( nonempty(
([Customers].[Account Name].[Account Name].MEMBERS * (lastperiods(13,[Time].[Fiscal Year].[Month].&[Aug-23])))
,[Measures].[M1]) ,
[Measures].[M2]>0 and
[Measures].[M2]<>-[Measures].[M3]))
select {[Measures].[SalesValue]} on columns,
non empty ([NamedSetName]) on rows from [CubeName]
```

In calculated named set I have used below query. But when we browse the cube in excel either i can drag named set or Time hierarchy.

```
Exists(
filter( nonempty(
([Customers].[Account Name].[Account Name].MEMBERS * (lastperiods(13,[Time].[Fiscal Year].CurrentMember)))
```

Comment: Dear experts kindly advise, whether it's achievable! or need to go with different methodology. Thank you.